# OffTop. Каким сервисом для менеджмента проектов вы пользуетесь?

Tags: project

Озадачил себя поиском сервиса для ведения задач по разработки программы. 
Из пожеланий:

1. ведение задач
2. вложенность списков 4 или более
3. отслеживание уже выполненных задач
4. доступность сервиса с нескольких устройств PC/смартфон
5. бесплатность
   (доступ к сервису для команды не требуется)

Вроде всего 5 штук, а найти не смог. Где-то нет нормального доступа с телефона (grantpro), а идея в голову может стукнуть внезапно. Где-то вложенные списки реализуемы до 3 (почти везде), а нужно дробить задачи на более мелкие части. Где-то фигово организован доступ к уже выполненным задачам (WunderList). Где-то во все не список задач, а список записок, которые нельзя отметить "выполненными" (onenote,  evernote)

На данный момент пользуюсь WunderList, но если проект разрастается, то пользоваться этим быстро становится не удобно.

Что посоветуете? 
Старый добрый метод, писать в блокнотике карандашиком и таскать его с собой или просто все, всегда и обо всем  помнить?

Comment: `Старый добрый метод, писать в блакнотике корандашиком` -- ну, да, в файликах редактором.

Comment: Именно для управления проектами, как мне кажется, больше всего подходит Wunderlist. Год-два назад искал себе таскменеджер для повседневных задач. Сам в итоге остановился на RememberTheMilk - там тоже есть многоуровневые списки в платной подписке, но мне не понравилось, как они реализованы и опять же доступ к выполненным задачам Вам покажется неудобным. Тут все зависит только от Вас, какой дизайн и функционал Вам понравится. Еще посмотрите ToDoist, Any.Do

Comment: WunderList неплох тем, что он простой можно быстро что то. А вот посмотреть уже выполнение уже неудобно. Установить важность (звездочка не в счет), фильтровать их нельзя, все в 1 куче. Как и сказал, хорошо до того момента, когда задачь мало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кому интересно, нашел бесплатное решение - Asana. Хоть и не идеально, но моим запросам удовлетворяет.

Answer (score 1):

Старая добрая JIRA - штука универсальная :) Из многочисленных андроклиентов больше всего нравится [JIRA Mobile Enterprise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infosysta.mobile.jira). И всё это комплексе с Confluence+Gitlab.

Comment: Jira - хороший сервис, но платный. А для команды из одного меня, зарабатывающим на своем софте 0 рублей, такой вариант не самый лучший. P. S. В поисках натыкался на уйму сервисов для крупных студий но за такой инструментарий хотят денег.

Comment: @Opossum, 1) в вопросе про бесплатность не было ни слова 2) $10 для self-hosted решения на 10 юзеров - неподъёмные деньги? Тогда вы не тем занимаетесь :)

Comment: согласен, про цену нужно было уточнить. Занимаюсь я учебой и пришёл к выводу, что даже тут нужен менеджмент, от того и потребность в сервисе. 10$? Как говорится - а зачем платить больше?